# Specific Email Address Validation - .NET Core MVC Model

Tags: regex, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC model, I have an attribute defined like

```
[Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
```

This one seems to be perfect for validating Email on user end. But  what I want is to validate Email that ends with **@mit.edu**. Example of Accepting Emails are :

- john@mit.edu
- amy@mit.edu

I want to reject all Emails without this format. Is there any way to define through **(even if with regex)** attributes in the model class?

Comment: Something like `[RegularExpression(@".+@mit\.edu", ErrorMessage = "You must use your mycompany email to register")]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EmailAddressAttribute` is a sealed class,we can't use `EmailAddressAttribute` to create custom validation class derived from it, but you can extend from `ValidationAttribute` when creating specific validation rules to email address field instead using default one.

```
public class CustomEmailAddressAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@mit.edu");
        if(!rgx.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"Please enter a valid email which ends with @mit.edu";
    }
}
```

Model:

```
[CustomEmailAddress]
public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
```

Or you could directly use regex validation, you could use below validation simply:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@mit.edu", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email which ends with @mit.edu")]
public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) post, maybe something like this could work:

```
((?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@mit\.edu)
```

This validates also the mail prefix itself. If you only need the suffix part, maybe this?

```
 .+@mit\.edu
```